# iOS app name with separate words

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I have developed an iOS app in FireMonkey XE5 (Update 2) and am deploying this on an actual device. **Is it possible to have the app name as two words with a space in between eg. "My App"**

One cannot include spaces in the project name in Delphi.

I cannot see any options to set this, and in the Deployment options I have changed the "Remote Name" of my project output file, but that does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name that appears under the icon on the IOS screen is in:
Project - Options - Version Info - CFBundleDisplayName.

You can change that to anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 11 - iOS system will delete simple spaces from a CFBundleDisplayName name.
So insert Unicode Character 'FIGURE SPACE'. Press Alt + 2007 - this will create this char: ╫ . Now recompile project - and you will see space in iOS project.
E.g.: My╫Project